# close a submenu when another menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I researched and attempted to implement some of the solutions provided, but I was unsuccessful. I modified my dropdown menu and click so that each submenu opens and closes when its parent is clicked. I'd like to have an open submenu close when a different menu is clicked so that they aren't all stacked at the menu bar. Could someone please tell me how I can do this? Thank you for your assistance.

I am using next js.

```html
 <div
      className={ classNames(classes.root, {
        [classes.rootActive]: active ,
        [classes.rootExpanded]: isMenuShrunk,
     
      })}
      ref={anchor}
      onClick={event => handleClick(event, menuItem) }

    >
      <button
        className={classes.menuItemBtn}
        data-test="menu-item-label"
        data-test-id={menuItem.testingContextId}
      >
        {menuItem.iconSrc && <div className={classNames(classes.icon, {
            [classes.icon]: isMenuShrunk
          })} > <SVG src={menuItem.iconSrc}/></div>}
        <Typography
          aria-label={menuItem.ariaLabel}
          className={classNames(classes.label, {
            [classes.hideLabel]: !isMenuShrunk
          })}
          variant="body2"
        >
          {menuItem.label}
        </Typography>
      </button>
      {menuItem.children && (
        <Collapse
         timeout="auto"
         unmountOnExit
         className={classNames({[classes.popper]: open && isMenuShrunk,})}
         in={open}
        >
      
            <div>
              {menuItem.children.map(subMenuItem => (
                <Typography
                  aria-label={subMenuItem.ariaLabel}
                  component="button"
                  className={classNames({[classes.subColor]:!color , [classes.subMenuLabel]:open||!open,
                      [classes.sublabel]:open||!open})}
                  key={subMenuItem.url}
                  onClick={event => handleClickSubMenu(event, subMenuItem)}
                  data-test="submenu-item-label"
                  data-test-id={subMenuItem.testingContextId}
                  variant="body2"
                >
                  {subMenuItem.label}
                </Typography>
              ))}
            </div>
        </Collapse>
      )}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions

***First***

make your `open` state a string instead of a boolean move it to the root level and store the opened `menu id` in it and also change the open condition like this `open==='menuId'` this will enable you to show only one opened menu at a time

***Second***

Use context API to wrap the whole menu in it and control the state from the context.